# Heroku: anonymize IP adresses in logfiles created by router

Tags: heroku

I'm talking about these lines inside my Heroku logs:

```
2013-06-13T09:45:46.580405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=example.com fwd="1.2.3.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=22
```

In particular the `1.2.3.4` part, which is the IP address of the user accessing my website.

By law I'm not allowed to save IP addresses. Is there any way to anonymize them?

Since Heroku will only save 1500 lines, the issue is not that big, since they're not stored forever. However, I'm using the Logentries Addon, is there a way I can anonymize the IP address?

Comment: You'd think that if this was a wider problem that the logging providers would have built the ability to anonymize logs in - but it's not something I've seen to be honest. What law are you concerned about?

Comment: Google Analytics has this built in, see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en It's not 100% regulated if IP addresses are considered personally identifiable information, in which case storage would not be allowed without consent.

Comment: Ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @Oliver no, I'm also not using Heroku anymore